# How to prevent loops with an event driven architecture

Tags: azure, events, event-handling

In our organization, we are implementing the [API LED Connectivity](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/learn-apis/api-led-connectivity/what-is-api-led-connectivity/) pattern together with an event driven architecture. We basically want source systems to publish events on which subscribers can react to do something, mostly updating their own source system.
There is one major issue with our design on which we currently have no solution. So we'd like to ask for your help!

Our problem is that events will trigger an update loop. Below picture describes in an extremely simplified way what we want, and what will happen:

[image]

An update in System A, will update System B, which will create an event and update System A, which will create an event and update System B etc. etc.

How can we stop this loop, considering the following:

We cannot prevent System B from sending events. Due to the complexity of many source systems, we have no influence on this. So System B will send events
We cannot ignore events of System B to System A, because there could be data in that event that really needs to be updated in System A
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: One option is to have System A append a unique id to the event to System B and have B include this id when it raises events itself. When A detects an event originating from B with a known id it can discard the event.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a LOT worse when there are systems C and D as well, and events are causing a loop a later in the chain due to publishers not having any knowledge of the events before they published a new one. Event-ids/Correlation-ids only get you so far.

The best solution I have come up with is ensuring that a Subscriber early-exits if no processing is needed, and does not generate the new event that causes the loop in the first place.

i.e. if a System doesn't actually change anything, don't let it send its Update Event. This makes a lot of edge cases disappear.

e.g. if the event/message is "update employee's address" and the address already matches, early-exit before sending any new events

This has numerous benefits when it comes to resubmitting failed events too.